# onPostExecute runs before doInBackground method is finished

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So,I simply made a login screen where the data comes from an external server.
All of that happens in the background method.it all works correctly except for onPost and onPre methods.
I don't think they are doing their job.

while the onBackground method is running i would like to:

1.Show a message if the data is right or wrong.

2.Show a custom progress dialog i made while doinbackground is running.

But neither of them work,any ideas?

Here is my code!

```
 public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String message = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        String userid = dename.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           progressDialog.showProgress(SignInAr.this,"Loading...",false);
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
                        message = "Please enter Username and Password";
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                            if (con == null) {
                                message = "Error in connection with SQL server please contact the administrator";
                                isSuccess = false;
                            } else {
                                String query = "SELECT * FROM CustomerData where CustomerMobile='" + userid + "' and CustomerPassword='" + password + "'";
                                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);




                                if(rs.next())
                                {
                                    String id = rs.getString("CustomerID");
                                    String mob = rs.getString("CustomerMobile");
                                    String lng = getIntent().getStringExtra("lng");
                                    String lat = getIntent().getStringExtra("lat");
                                    message = "Welcome " + userid;
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInAr.this,agzakhana_mainAr.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
                                    intent.putExtra("lng",lng);
                                    intent.putExtra("nameid",id);
                                    String getname = rs.getString("CustomerName");
                                    intent.putExtra("nameofcus",getname);
                                    intent.putExtra("mob",mob);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                    isSuccess=true;



                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    message = "Wrong info";
                                    isSuccess = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            isSuccess = false;
                            message = "Exceptions"+ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            return message;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

           progressDialog.hideProgress();
            System.out.println("Message is: "+ r + "and isSuccess = "+ isSuccess);

            if(!isSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(SignInAr.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is how i call the asynctask:

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                doLogin.execute();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Show how you call your async task.

Comment: @blackapps Just edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return value before thread run. Simple to fix it you shoukd remove `Thread` and `Runnable` in method `doInBackground` because in `AsyncTask` it already make `doInBackground` run in `Background Thread`.

Comment: I don't know what to say except thank you.
It worked perfect!